# Anchor tag click method not working in internet explore 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I want to stimulate automatic download using JavaScript.

Below is my code.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = filepath;
a.download = filename;
a.click();
```

`a.click()` method is working fine with my Chrome browser but not working in `IE 11/ 10` browser. Can anybody help me with this.

Edit 1 : my requirement is simple. i want create anchor tag, add file path and my new file name and Click method it will download file with new name. it is working on Chrome browser but not working on IE browser. As per my finding IE does not support download attribute with anchor tag.

Comment: why not `window.location.href = filepath;`

Comment: @sharky i want to change filename while downloading this file.

Comment: are you using jquery?¿ and what version?¿

Comment: i am using javascript

Answer (score 0):

the .click function must work in IE 11, you could try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spachecojimenez/b15sL45j/2/):

The main problem must be the way that you download the file. First of all, Could do you look the log in the IE console when you execute your code?

```
Object doesn't support this action
```

Appear this error?

Comment: i think it work fine on button. but i want to do it on anchor tag. so i can add hyperlink of file and change file name using download attribute.

Comment: The click method works to in a "a" tag, I modify the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/spachecojimenez/b15sL45j/4/).

Comment: i agrre with you click method works on a tag. but it does not download fiile. i will edit my question in which i will write full scenario.